# how can I sort dictionary whose key is tuple and value is int?

Tags: python, sorting

I have a dictionary like `prob = {('be', 'limited'): 0.004, ('the', 'book'): 0.000432, ......}`

for sorting I used

```
for k, v in sorted(prob, key = lambda x: x[1], reverse = True):
    print k, v
```

but it doesn't give the result. ( it just gave me the tuples..) I wanna sort that dictionary according to value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call `sorted` with `prob.items()` otherwise it returns just the keys after sorting takes place.

```
sorted(prob.items(), key = lambda x: x[1], reverse = True)
```

You can store it into `collection.OrderedDict` which remembers the order in which the items were added:

```
>>> dct = sorted(prob.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
>>> result = collections.OrderedDict(dct)
```